# Adding more than one image as album art to mp3 via command line

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, script, mp3

I want to add two images (front and back cover) to my converted mp3s. At this time I convert all my WAVs with [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/), then I convert the ID3 tag version from 2.3 to 2.4 via [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) and then I will add two pictures but with eyeD3 I could not set up two images. If I add a front cover and later a back cover the front cover will be deleted.

So thats my questions: How could I insert/embed two images as front [(APIC Type 03)](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Attached_picture) and back cover [(APIC Type 04)](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Attached_picture) into an mp3 via command line? At best it should run on OSX and Linux.

Comment: The open-source "id3v2" (git://git.code.sf.net/p/id3v2/git) can programmatically insert artwork, but I'm not sure it can insert 2 images.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn´t find any informations how I could add a picture. Do you have an example line?

Comment: Looks like it's `id3v2 --APIC <image-filename> <mp3-filename>`

Comment: For id3v2 version 0.1.12 it doesn´t work. But I´ve contacted the developer from eyeD3 and he will fix it. So thanks for your help and if you know how I could do it with id3v2 I will like to know too :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to add more than one image to a MP3 with eyeD3. To do this you have to add a description to each image tag like:

```
eyeD3 --force-update --no-color --quiet --add-image "frontcoverimage.jpg:FRONT_COVER:front cover" --add-image "backcoverimage.jpg:BACK_COVER:back cover" file.mp3
```

The developer of eyeD3 said:

> The ID3 spec says that if there are multiple images in a single tag
>   than each must have
>   a unique description.